# How to modify Hardware UUID of a macOS Sierra Virtual machine in VMware fusion/parallel desktop

Tags: macos, virtualization, vmware, parallels-desktop

I've got to have different Hardware UUID for software testing purposes.
When cloning a VM in Fusion pro 8.5, the clone gets a new MAC address but the hardware  UUID in system report in macOS doesn't change.

Any idea how I can assign a new UUID to virtual Mac guest OS?

Comment: Similar Question on Stack Overflow: [*Changing Mac Hardware UUID on a Parallels 11 VM*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34699144/642706). Refers to this Parallels Support document: [*How to change the virtual machine UUID*](http://kb.parallels.com/en/11197).

Answer (score 4):

The text file that Fusion uses to assign this is editable when the VM is powered off (don't suspend, shut down the OS):

1. Turn off VM
2. In machine folder, change `uuid.bios` section in `<>.vmx` file (f e.g. `uuid.bios = "aa aa ..."`).
3. In machine folder delete `.nvram` file
4. Boot VM

In "About this MAC" you must see
[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the case anymore. VMware Fusion 11.5.7 generates a UUID that is then stored in nvram